# unclear instruction in groovy install from source

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After finishing section 2.1 (Building Catkin Packages) and sourcing the catkin workspace section 2.2 (Build Rosbuild Packages) starts with mkdir ros_ws.

What I would like clarified is where to put the ros_ws directory. After finishing 2.1 the system is still in the ros_catkin_ws so to follow the instructions exactly will place the ros_ws inside the ros_catkin_ws.

So, should ros_ws be inside the ros_catkin_ws?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62359/unclear-instruction-in-groovy-install-from-source/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Section 2.2 tells you to create it in your home folder, from the tutorial:

```
$ mkdir ~/ros_ws
$ cd ~/ros_ws
$ rosws init . ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
```

I don't see the confusion, but the location of the `ros_ws` doesn't matter, though personally I would keep it separate from the `catkin_ws` as not to confuse them.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-05-07**:
Thanks for the answer. This is what I suspected and I agree it should be kept separate from the catkin_ws and thus the question. I've reread the installation wiki (http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source) several times and I still don't see a reference to putting rosws in the home folder.